# Is type casting needed when using NOT (~) operator on a literal integer against a 64bit variable

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

Will the following work, if not what are the rules of auto type-casting that prevent it from working?

```
uint64_t u64val=3293;
#define ALIGNsize 4
u64val=(u64val+ALIGNsize-1)&~(ALIGNsize-1);
```

Or is this required:

```
uint64_t u64val=3293;
#define ALIGNsize 4
u64val=(u64val+ALIGNsize-1)&~((uint64_t)ALIGNsize-1);
```

If the later, are there any tricks to automate things so it's not wasteful using 32bit but still works in 64bit without having to remember or know the data size?

Comment: How about: `enum { ALIGNsize = 4ULL };`?

Comment: If the value is less than 32 bits it will be promoted to 32 bits before the unary operators are applied. But a 32 bit value will not be promoted to 64 bits before the unary operators are applied to so you need to cast it or define the values as 64 bit with say `#define ALIGNsize 4ull`

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yup.

Comment: `u64val += ALIGNsize - 1;` `u64val ^= u64val & (ALIGNsize - 1);`

Comment: @CraigEstey aren't enumerators treated as having type `int`?

Comment: Hmm, I knew of using ULL on the constant, but then wouldn't it be wasteful in 32bit code or is compiler smart enough to optimize it?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons the underlying type defaults to *an* integer type large enough to hold the biggest specified value.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Yes, that is correct. From C11 6.7.2.2 p2: *"The expression that defines the value of an enumeration constant shall be an integer
constant expression that has a value representable as an **int**."*

Comment: @Swordfish My understanding is that the identifier itself is an `int` specifically, but an instance of an `enum` can have different implementation-defined types.  See 6.7.2.2 of the C11 standard. *The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.*  The next paragraph talks about the enumeration object rather than identifier: *Each  enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. [...] shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.*

Comment: @ChristianGibbons [dcl.enum/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#7) The question is tagged with both languages which should be avoided.

Comment: You have defined it as `uint64_t u64val` so what is the objection to a `(uint64_t)ALIGNsize` cast?

Comment: @WeatherVane It's about the type of the operand in the subexpression.

Comment: @Swordfish Of course the one time I let the OP slide with dual-tagging, the problems come out to play (I assume, I actually haven't read your link yet since it's blocked by my work firewall for some reason).

Comment: @ChristianGibbons *For an enum whose underlying type is not fixed the underlying type is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. If no integral type can represent all the enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed. It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than int unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned int. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test and as far as alignment using NOT (~) I think I came up with something generic that works.   Both for C and C++ (tested in C++).  Here the sample app.  Is this good or am I missing something (want to ensure before accepting as answer):

```
// TestAlign.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// alignment to a base2 factor

inline uint64_t AlignUp2(uint64_t value, int align)
{
  return (value+align-1)&~((uint64_t) align-1);
}

inline uint32_t AlignUp2(uint32_t value, int align)
{
  return (value+align-1)&~((uint32_t) align-1);
}

#define ALIGNUP232(value, align) ((value+align-1)&~((uint32_t) align-1))
#define ALIGNUP264(value, align) ((value+align-1)&~((uint64_t)align-1))
#define ALIGNUP2(value, align) ((sizeof(value)==4) ? ALIGNUP232(value, align) : ALIGNUP264(value, align))
 
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
  if (argc<3) {
    _tprintf(_T("Usage: testgenericitems value alignvalue\n"));
    return 1;
  }

  uint64_t val64=_tcstoull(argv[1], NULL, 0);
  uint32_t val32=_tcstoul(argv[1], NULL, 0);

  uint32_t align=_tcstoul(argv[2], NULL, 0);

  uint32_t val32test;
  val32test=val32;
  val32test=(val32test+align-1) & ~(align-1);

  uint64_t val64test;
  val64test=val64;
  val64test=(val64test+align-1) & ~(align-1);

  _tprintf(_T("32bit Old Style Align %u up to multiple of %i = %u\n"), val32, align, val32test);
  _tprintf(_T("64bit Old Style Align %llu up to multiple of %i = %llu\n"), val64, align, val64test);

  val32test=val32;
  val32test=AlignUp2(val32test, align);

  val64test=val64;
  val64test=AlignUp2(val64test, align);

  _tprintf(_T("32bit c++ Align %u up to multiple of %i = %u\n"), val32, align, val32test);
  _tprintf(_T("64bit c++ Align %llu up to multiple of %i = %llu\n"), val64, align, val64test);

  val32test=val32;
  val32test=ALIGNUP2(val32test, align);

  val64test=val64;
  val64test=ALIGNUP2(val64test, align);

  _tprintf(_T("32bit c Align %u up to multiple of %i = %u\n"), val32, align, val32test);
  _tprintf(_T("64bit c Align %llu up to multiple of %i = %llu\n"), val64, align, val64test);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: if it were me, I'd check tie `sizeof()` against 8,  that way `short`s and `char`s would use the 32 bit version.